# Tag search should match middle of synonyms

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tag-synonyms, search

Go to [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) and, in the "Type to find tags" search box, type in a string. The page will auto-update with tags that match that string. However, it seems based on a few tries that the string will match only:

- a real, usable tag (as opposed to a synonym), no matter where in the tag's name it matches, and
- a synonym, where it matches the *start* of the synonym.

(Things I've tried: searching `maz`, `birk`, `zik`, `min`, and `quo`.)

If this is by design, I request it be changed, and the search match even the middle of synonym names. But I suspect it's a bug.

Comment: This is currently by design, but we'll see about modifying the SQL that powers this search to include partial matches in the middle of the tag for synonyms.

Comment: We still think this is a good idea, but unfortunately it's not going to happen any time soon.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174044

Comment: And similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224818